# Should "japanese" be capitalised when used as an adjective

Tags: orthography, capitalization, proper-nouns

Which one of these is the correct usage:

> 1) Your favourite Japanese restaurant
>
> 2) Your favourite japanese restaurant (being an adjective in this
>   case, it should be in lower case)

Comment: In English country names, and their associated adjectives and languages are always capitalised. In some languages, such as French, only the country name is capitalised - the language and people are not.

Answer (score 21):

Generally speaking, nations and nationalities are capitalized.  This is always the case with things, like cuisine or history, that are closely associated with the the country.  Thus **Japanese** cuisine (not japanese cuisine) and **Chinese** dynastic history (not chinese dynastic history).

There are a small number of exceptions, when the item described has a more remote connection.  Thus

> We'll use the good china

(not "the good China") to describe porcelain or vitreous dinnerware.  And

> japanned furniture

(not Japanned furniture) to describe black lacquered furniture.  Opinion is divided on whether to capitalize *english* to describe the spin of a ball.

Comment: What is an "english spin of a ball" - I've never heard it before?

Comment: How about "dutch courage", or "french leave"? Or "welching" on a bet. I'm not sure whether we capitalise those or not.

Comment: @WS2 Here "english" is an American English term (Br.Eng. "side") for putting [sidespin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sports_techniques#Sidespin_(english)) on the cueball in Billiards/Snooker/Pool.  Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38397/why-is-putting-some-spin-on-a-ball-described-in-some-circles-as-giving-it-some

Answer (score 3):

In English country names, and their associated adjectives and languages are always capitalised.

In some languages, such as French, only the country name is capitalised - the language and people are not.

Comment: In French, Spanish, German, and, I'm sure, in many other European languages, adjectives in general are all lowercase.

Comment: @aabeba I thought German capitalised even more than English.

Comment: Yes, @Lawrence, it does. It capitalizes all Nouns. But it does not capitalize any other Words at all (except for *Sie* "you" to distinguish it from other Meanings of the same Word). Thus what aabeba said is correct. In Fact, it means German has no Need to distinguish between proper Nouns (or other Parts of Speech) and common Words at all.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thank you, that’s very helpful. I can see the same pattern now in English work translated from German.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [capitalization rules set out in GrammarBook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp)

> **Rule 2.** Capitalize proper nouns—and adjectives derived from proper nouns.
>
> Examples:
>   the Golden Gate Bridge
>   the Grand Canyon
>   a Russian song
>   a Shakespearean sonnet
>   a Freudian slip

In any Grammar book it shall be clear that sentence #1 – **"Your favourite Japanese restaurant"** – is the correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

According to guidelines in the Chicago Manual of Style, the point of capitalising an adjective is to convey the literal relationship to the proper root noun. So, if you're trying to say that the food comes from there, or the restaurant is in Japan, or is staffed by Japanese persons, or is owned by a Japanese owner, or anything that literally ties it to Japan in a material way, it's appropriate to capitalise the adjective. If you're simply describing the style of the cuisine, a lower-case adjective is acceptable.

Comment: Sorry? "We're going to have japanese-style food"? Really? In what variety of English is this acceptable? Can you corroborate that assertion with a quote from CMOS?

Answer (score 0):

*Japan* (the country) is capitalized.  And the adjective form *Japanese*.
*Japanese* (the language) is capitalized.
But *japan* (the hard black varnish) is not.  Which means it is legal to use in Scrabble!

Comment: I've never heard of "japan" being used to describe lacquer... Sounds wrong to me as Japanese-American 

Comment: It's a very well known and named form of finish applied to furniture. Also, there is a type of finish used on screws called black japanned. I guess it's not something you might come across if you aren't involved with the trades that use the screws or if you deal in antique furniture. I am British and it might surprise you to know that we don't use the same language to describe how we would like our eggs done. 'Over easy" is nirvana description the vast majority of English people would understand. "Divided by a common language" is a phrase often used to make this point. Japanese lacquered furni